# Cache options for SharePoint Internet site to reduce N/W bandwidth

Tags: 2013, cache

we have one requirement to reduce bandwidth of our network and we have public internet published site that is in SharePoint 2013,now i am looking for some options like cache SharePoint 2013 web application out of our network instead of hosting whole SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host static assets (images/CSS/JS references in *most* cases) on a CDN. The actual SharePoint site itself cannot be.

Comment: Hi can you give me some examples how to configure CDN for SharePoint and how to configure them.

Comment: The CDN is independent of SharePoint; there is no integration. You instead reference images on pages, etc. from the CDN URL. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/.